# QTWidget displays twice on just one click

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I have a Qdialog like the following:
[image]

and another one which gets triggered when I click "OK" without selecting the image and classifier files both, like here
[image]

I have linked the Browse... buttons to QFileDialog. Now, when I click on **Browse for the Image** button, it opens a file dialog, then when I select the file and press OK, it reopens it. Same thing happens with the other browse button and the dialog containing the label.

Any idea, why is it happening 2 times when the event has only occurred once?
Here are the slots:

```
void MySecondQtProject::on_pushImage_clicked()
{
    image =
        QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("open file"), "C:/Users/mankum93/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/BananaClassifierOpenCV/BananaClassifierOpenCV",
        "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)");
}

void MySecondQtProject::on_pushClassifier_clicked()
{
    classifier =
        QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("open file"), "C:/Users/mankum93/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/BananaClassifierOpenCV/BananaClassifierOpenCV",
        "XML files (*.xml)");
}

void MySecondQtProject::on_pushOK_clicked()
{
    accept();

    //Now lets compare for invalidity of any string:
    if (image.isNull() || classifier.isNull())
    {
        ShowErrorDialog dialog(this);
        dialog.exec();
    }
    else
    {
        //Convert Qstring to std::string
        String imageFileName = image.toLocal8Bit().constData();
        String cascadeFileName = classifier.toLocal8Bit().constData();

        // Now, we can go to main detection logic
        detectObject(imageFileName, cascadeFileName);
    }
}
```

**PS:** I am a newbie to QT

**EDIT 1:** The meta object code

```
void MySecondQtProject::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        MySecondQtProject *_t = static_cast<MySecondQtProject *>(_o);
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: _t->on_pushImage_clicked(); break;
        case 1: _t->on_pushClassifier_clicked(); break;
        case 2: _t->on_pushOK_clicked(); break;
        default: ;
        }
    }
    Q_UNUSED(_a);
}
```

**EDIT2 :** Code for UI files

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'mysecondqtprojectHp7256.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.4.1
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef MYSECONDQTPROJECTHP7256_H
#define MYSECONDQTPROJECTHP7256_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MySecondQtProjectClass
{
public:
    QPushButton *pushOK;
    QWidget *layoutWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QPushButton *pushImage;
    QPushButton *pushClassifier;

    void setupUi(QDialog *MySecondQtProjectClass)
    {
        if (MySecondQtProjectClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            MySecondQtProjectClass->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MySecondQtProjectClass"));
        MySecondQtProjectClass->resize(600, 272);
        pushOK = new QPushButton(MySecondQtProjectClass);
        pushOK->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushOK"));
        pushOK->setGeometry(QRect(290, 220, 91, 31));
        layoutWidget = new QWidget(MySecondQtProjectClass);
        layoutWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("layoutWidget"));
        layoutWidget->setGeometry(QRect(200, 100, 181, 91));
        verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(layoutWidget);
        verticalLayout->setSpacing(6);
        verticalLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        verticalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("verticalLayout"));
        verticalLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pushImage = new QPushButton(layoutWidget);
        pushImage->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushImage"));

        verticalLayout->addWidget(pushImage);

        pushClassifier = new QPushButton(layoutWidget);
        pushClassifier->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushClassifier"));

        verticalLayout->addWidget(pushClassifier);


        retranslateUi(MySecondQtProjectClass);
        QObject::connect(pushImage, SIGNAL(clicked()), MySecondQtProjectClass, SLOT(on_pushImage_clicked()));
        QObject::connect(pushClassifier, SIGNAL(clicked()), MySecondQtProjectClass, SLOT(on_pushClassifier_clicked()));
        QObject::connect(pushOK, SIGNAL(clicked()), MySecondQtProjectClass, SLOT(on_pushOK_clicked()));

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MySecondQtProjectClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QDialog *MySecondQtProjectClass)
    {
        MySecondQtProjectClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MySecondQtProjectClass", "MySecondQtProject", 0));
        pushOK->setText(QApplication::translate("MySecondQtProjectClass", "OK", 0));
        pushImage->setText(QApplication::translate("MySecondQtProjectClass", "Browse for the Image", 0));
        pushClassifier->setText(QApplication::translate("MySecondQtProjectClass", "Browse for the classifier", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MySecondQtProjectClass: public Ui_MySecondQtProjectClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // MYSECONDQTPROJECTHP7256_H
```

Now, code for the other errordialog:

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'showerrordialogmU7256.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.4.1
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef SHOWERRORDIALOGMU7256_H
#define SHOWERRORDIALOGMU7256_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_ShowErrorDialog
{
public:
    QLabel *label;

    void setupUi(QDialog *ShowErrorDialog)
    {
        if (ShowErrorDialog->objectName().isEmpty())
            ShowErrorDialog->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("ShowErrorDialog"));
        ShowErrorDialog->resize(400, 65);
        label = new QLabel(ShowErrorDialog);
        label->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label"));
        label->setGeometry(QRect(70, 20, 241, 21));

        retranslateUi(ShowErrorDialog);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(ShowErrorDialog);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QDialog *ShowErrorDialog)
    {
        ShowErrorDialog->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("ShowErrorDialog", "ShowErrorDialog", 0));
        label->setText(QApplication::translate("ShowErrorDialog", "Please properly select the Image or the classifier", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class ShowErrorDialog: public Ui_ShowErrorDialog {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // SHOWERRORDIALOGMU7256_H
```

Code for main Cpp file

```
#include "mysecondqtproject.h"
#include "showerrordialog.h"
#include <QFileDialog>

#include "objectdetect.h"

MySecondQtProject::MySecondQtProject(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

MySecondQtProject::~MySecondQtProject()
{

}

void MySecondQtProject::on_pushImage_clicked()
{
    image =
        QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("open file"), "C:/Users/mankum93/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/BananaClassifierOpenCV/BananaClassifierOpenCV",
        "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)");
}

void MySecondQtProject::on_pushClassifier_clicked()
{
    classifier =
        QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("open file"), "C:/Users/mankum93/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/BananaClassifierOpenCV/BananaClassifierOpenCV",
        "XML files (*.xml)");
}

void MySecondQtProject::on_pushOK_clicked()
{
    accept();

    //Now lets compare for invalidity of any string:
    if (image.isNull() || classifier.isNull())
    {
        ShowErrorDialog dialog(this);
        dialog.exec();
    }
    else
    {
        //Convert Qstring to std::string
        String imageFileName = image.toLocal8Bit().constData();
        String cascadeFileName = classifier.toLocal8Bit().constData();

        // Now, we can go to main detection logic
        detectObject(imageFileName, cascadeFileName);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3 :** Here are the rest of the useful files you might wanna see

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'mysecondqtproject.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.4.1
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_MYSECONDQTPROJECT_H
#define UI_MYSECONDQTPROJECT_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MySecondQtProjectClass
{
public:
    QPushButton *pushOK;
    QWidget *layoutWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QPushButton *pushImage;
    QPushButton *pushClassifier;

    void setupUi(QDialog *MySecondQtProjectClass)
    {
        if (MySecondQtProjectClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            MySecondQtProjectClass->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MySecondQtProjectClass"));
        MySecondQtProjectClass->resize(600, 272);
        pushOK = new QPushButton(MySecondQtProjectClass);
        pushOK->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushOK"));
        pushOK->setGeometry(QRect(290, 220, 91, 31));
        layoutWidget = new QWidget(MySecondQtProjectClass);
        layoutWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("layoutWidget"));
        layoutWidget->setGeometry(QRect(200, 100, 181, 91));
        verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(layoutWidget);
        verticalLayout->setSpacing(6);
        verticalLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        verticalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("verticalLayout"));
        verticalLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pushImage = new QPushButton(layoutWidget);
        pushImage->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushImage"));

        verticalLayout->addWidget(pushImage);

        pushClassifier = new QPushButton(layoutWidget);
        pushClassifier->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushClassifier"));

        verticalLayout->addWidget(pushClassifier);


        retranslateUi(MySecondQtProjectClass);
        QObject::connect(pushImage, SIGNAL(clicked()), MySecondQtProjectClass, SLOT(on_pushImage_clicked()));
        QObject::connect(pushClassifier, SIGNAL(clicked()), MySecondQtProjectClass, SLOT(on_pushClassifier_clicked()));
        QObject::connect(pushOK, SIGNAL(clicked()), MySecondQtProjectClass, SLOT(on_pushOK_clicked()));

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MySecondQtProjectClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QDialog *MySecondQtProjectClass)
    {
        MySecondQtProjectClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MySecondQtProjectClass", "MySecondQtProject", 0));
        pushOK->setText(QApplication::translate("MySecondQtProjectClass", "OK", 0));
        pushImage->setText(QApplication::translate("MySecondQtProjectClass", "Browse for the Image", 0));
        pushClassifier->setText(QApplication::translate("MySecondQtProjectClass", "Browse for the classifier", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MySecondQtProjectClass: public Ui_MySecondQtProjectClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MYSECONDQTPROJECT_H
```

And the second one:

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'showerrordialog.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.4.1
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_SHOWERRORDIALOG_H
#define UI_SHOWERRORDIALOG_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_ShowErrorDialog
{
public:
    QLabel *label;

    void setupUi(QDialog *ShowErrorDialog)
    {
        if (ShowErrorDialog->objectName().isEmpty())
            ShowErrorDialog->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("ShowErrorDialog"));
        ShowErrorDialog->resize(400, 65);
        label = new QLabel(ShowErrorDialog);
        label->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label"));
        label->setGeometry(QRect(70, 20, 241, 21));

        retranslateUi(ShowErrorDialog);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(ShowErrorDialog);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QDialog *ShowErrorDialog)
    {
        ShowErrorDialog->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("ShowErrorDialog", "ShowErrorDialog", 0));
        label->setText(QApplication::translate("ShowErrorDialog", "Please properly select the Image or the classifier", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class ShowErrorDialog: public Ui_ShowErrorDialog {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_SHOWERRORDIALOG_H
```

Comment: Hey, can you add the different "connect" line where you link your button's signal to your slots above ?

Comment: @Martin : I didn't understand. What do you mean? can you make it more clear?(I am a newbie to QT)(different as in...?)

Comment: Huum ok, you use Qt designer to set up your signal/slot mecanism (have a look at this very important Qt feature). I don't have Qt here but on Qt designer, you can right clic and select an option like "create slot associated to button", and it generates the function on_push....... like we see above right ? In fact, when you clic on a button, you emit a signal which then call the associated slot on_push...... . The problem is probably you didn't choose the right option when pushing the push button. You have to choose "triggered()". Hope it's clear enough :/

Comment: @Martin : Well...you see, First of all, I didn't use the automatic option "create slot associated to button" because I couldn't find it at that time(and even now), I just created the name of slot from configure menu, then went to the code and created the handle function myself. The code worked after all handling the event but with  a glitch. Btw, in configure menu, there is clicked() and others but no triggered()

Comment: I advise you to only use Qt designer to put buttons, widgets, layout, whatever and that's all. If you want to connect your buttons to slots, do it via writing code. For example in your class MySecondQtProject constructor, write "connect(ui->pushButtonBrowseImage, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushImage_clicked()))".

Comment: @Martin : The thing is, I am creating Qt code with Visual Studio Plugin, there is supposed to be meta object compiler acting behind the scenes. I saw the generated file, it contains "special" code for the handlers. If I were to insert my own calls, I doubt the whole meta mechanism will work at all. I will try your suggestion though, for sure...

Comment: The connect stuff should be in the generated ui_*.h file in the UI_DIR. Maybe there is a double connection?

Comment: @Martin your advice is incorrect. Using Qt Designer for creating slots is perfectly fine, and your way is a bit harmful because `on_pushImage_clicked` slot will be connected to corresponding signal automatically, so your connect statement is useless (I wonder if it would even result in double connection). pulp_fiction, show the constructor and .ui file contents, please.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov : Code added :|

Comment: You should also have something like `MySecondQtProjectClass.ui`, it's an XML file. Can you post it? There is a problem in `Ui_MySecondQtProjectClass`, but this code is auto-generated (unless you edited it yourself, which you shouldn't do), so the problem needs to be fixed in the form editor or manually in XML.

Comment: I assure you my advice is not incorrect at all. Having your connect functions in your code make it easily readable. I have never said that it doesn't work with Qt Designer, it's just that you don't have any visible code of the connection. Obviously if you do both you'll have double connection but again I didn't say to to do both. Anyway, up to you to work as you want.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov : I assure you there is no xml file. I did a manual search in the project folder but didn't find any. Anyway, I have posted the 2 form files that might be worth looking into.(See EDIT 3)

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with the VS plugin. Anyway, in `setupUi` function you have `QObject::connect` statements that shouldn't be there. `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()` does all necessary connects, so you have two connects for each slot, resulting in double invocation. As I said, ui*.h files are auto-generated, so you should change something in the form editor instead of editing these files.